# How Can I get Tableau to just Pull a Specific Data Point

Tags: database, tableau-api, percentage, calculated-field

I am new to Tableau and am trying to figure out how to isolate a row of data in a calculated field.
For example, to get a certain piece of data for a certain year only and then use that for calculations.
I want to find the percentage change using a calculated field between undocumented immigration growth from 2000-2010-2018.

I have tried the following to just try to isolate the value point for 2018:

`(IF  STR([Year])='2018'  THEN [Undocmented Population] ELSE NULL end)` 
and also this but it needs to be aggregate measures:

`{ FIXED [State]: IF  STR([Year])='2018'  THEN [Undocmented Population] ELSE NULL end}`

I just want to isolate the date points for the various years per state so then I can perform a simple change in percentage calculation and cannot seem to figure out how to do it...

[Tableau Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTghF.png)

Comment: Are you calculating the YoY change in Tableau or it comes pre-calculated in the data?

Comment: I'm calculating it as a table calculation. But the other column I can't get it to do so properly because there are gaps in the data  so that is why I was trying to figure out how to make a calculated field to do it.

Comment: Have you considered filtering out the records where [Undocumented Population] is null?